# High order functions - receive lambda func for derivative calculation

Tags: python, math, lambda, higher-order-functions

Im new to python and ive been trying to implement a numerical derivative high order function but I can't modify my code to have the desired result:

```
def deriv(f):
    return lambda x: ((f(x + h) - f(x)) / h)
```

But when calling the function im getting an error i cant iterpret.

Comment: How do you call it? Please share that code too

Comment: print(deriv(lamda x: x**2)(4)) and the expected result is 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Next time I suggest adding the error description in order to help us help you better.

In this case, I suppose you are probably missing the definition of the variable h.
try adding this line to your code:

```
def derivative(f):
    h=0.000001
    return lambda x: ((f(x + h) - f(x)) / h)
```

or:

```
def deriv(f, h=0.000001):
    return lambda x: ((f(x + h) - f(x)) / h)
```